# Is it possible to install the stdlib module then use a resource provided by the same module within the same puppet manifest file

Tags: puppet

> This puppet manifest file searches and replaces the ULIMIT to a value
> of 3000
> The file_line resource is available in the stdlib class and depends on
> the exec

```
exec { 'install_puppetlabs_stdlib':
  command     => '/usr/bin/puppet module install puppetlabs-stdlib',
  unless      => '/usr/bin/puppet module list | grep puppetlabs-stdlib',
  path        => ['/bin', '/opt/puppet/bin', '/usr/bin'],
  notify      => Class['import_stdlib'],
  refreshonly => true,
}

class import_stdlib {
  include stdlib

  file_line { 'modify_nginx_config':
    ensure  => present,
    line    => 'ULIMIT="-n 3000"',
    match   => '^ULIMIT.*$',
    path    => '/etc/default/nginx',
  }
}


class { 'import_stdlib': }
```

## command Execution Error

```
local_Apply:# puppet apply version.pp
Error: Could not find class stdlib
```

Comment: Is software like CodeManager, r10k, librarian-puppet etc. not an option?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to install the stdlib module then use a resource provided by the same module within the same puppet manifest file

Not on the same Puppet run, no.  Any modules on which your manifests depend must be available during catalog building, and that is done before any resources are applied.

Side note: you do not need to `include stdlib` to use any of the module's functions or resource types, including `file_line`.  But that does not rescue you from needing to have the module installed already at catalog-building time.

Comment: this means that it is therefore, necessary that I have two puppet apply manifest files. One to install the dependencies then the second manifest to apply resource changes ? I needed the puppet file to be run once in one go. Again is it possible to write one manifest file that performs a bootstrap so that when it installs the dependencies it creates temporary puppet file then executes it? I haven't tried the latter but perhaps a few pointers could suffice

Comment: @TitusCheserem, one alternative might be to ditch `puppet apply` (which is deprecated, anyway) and instead use the `puppet agent` instead, together with a puppet server.  You would need to install stdlib on the server, once, but all the agents retrieving catalogs from it would get stdlib and any other required modules automatically.

Comment: @TitusCheserem, you cannot directly start one Puppet run from within another, however, because Puppet blocks concurrent runs (for good reason).  You could, conceivably, have one run *schedule* a second one, however, or you could write a wrapper script that performs the two runs. Or a script that directly ensures stdlib installed before starting a run.

Comment: Or, @TitusCheserem, you could include installing stdlib in whatever procedure you're using to provision your nodes with Puppet in the first place.  Then you won't need to worry about it being missing.